# How to do a bootstrap accordion filled by a database?

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is a Frequently Asked Questions using bootstrap accordion.

Right now, my listview is filled with my database in codebehind. But, the problem is it's always the div "collapseOne" that's opening no mather which question i'm clicking. I would need to change dynamically the "href" and the div's ID "collapseOne" into "collapseTwo", "collapseThree" etc. depending on what's in my table.

How can I do that?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lviewFAQ" runat="server"
              ItemType="Site_de_la_Technique_Informatique.Model.FAQ"
              SelectMethod="SelectFAQ"
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="lviewFAQ_SelectedIndexChanged">

              <LayoutTemplate>
                   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
              </LayoutTemplate>

              <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionFAQ" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.texteQuestion %>'></asp:Label>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReponseFAQ" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.texteReponse %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And the code for filling the listview with the questions :

```
public IQueryable<Model.FAQ> SelectFAQ()
        {
            List<Model.FAQ> listeDesQuestions = null;

            using (LeModelTIContainer lecontexte = new LeModelTIContainer()) { 
                try
                {
                    listeDesQuestions = (from faq in lecontexte.FAQSet select faq).ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text += "Erreur s'est produite lors du SelectFAQ : " + ex.ToString();
                }
            }
            return listeDesQuestions.AsQueryable();
        }
```

I'd really like to have a solution full-c#, with no javascript. But I don't think it's possible. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, thanks for your reply. It didn't work though. I think it was because I had `runat="server"` in my controls.

I played around your suggestion and came up with this :

```
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%# Item.IDFAQ %>">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionFAQ" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.texteQuestion %>'></asp:Label>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse<%# Item.IDFAQ %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblReponseFAQ" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.texteReponse %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Which did the trick for me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use placeholders in your `ItemTemplate`

`<a class="accordion-toggle" ... href="#collapseOne"`

and

`<div id="collapseOne"...`

can be replaced with

`<a class="accordion-toggle" ... href="#<%# BindItem.linkName %>"`

and

`<div id="<%# BindItem.linkName %>"...`

substitute `linkName` with a suitable property from the `FAQSet` object

Comment: Because I was using the ListView which @Mymozaaa was also using I found that Item instead BindItem was needed to implement your excellent solution.